# OpenCL + SDL 2.0 (with OpenGL context) crash on SDL_Quit()

Tags: linux, opengl, sdl, opencl, glfw

If I call clGetPlatformIDs and directly after it SDL_Quit(), the program crashes (segfault). The OpenGL version doesn't seem to matter at all (tried 2.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3). The operating system is Fedora 18, fully updated. I have installed the fglrx drivers.

The problem doesn't seem to be SDL-only; GLFW had a very similar crash on glfwTerminate().
GLFW didn't tell me anything about the crash, except that it was a segfault. But luckily, SDL gives a bit more information:

```
*** glibc detected *** bin/Debug/voxel renderer: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001086220 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x322c87ca8e]
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xb0a56)[0x7f256e97ba56]
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_VideoQuit+0x6e)[0x7f256e960d4e]
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_QuitSubSystem+0x18d)[0x7f256e8daded]
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_Quit+0x18)[0x7f256e8daf18]
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0x10d5f)[0x7f256e8dbd5f]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x322d00f000]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 13762941                           /home/julius/Ohjelmointi/Raytracer/bin/Debug/voxel renderer
00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 fd:02 13762941                           /home/julius/Ohjelmointi/Raytracer/bin/Debug/voxel renderer
00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 fd:02 13762941                           /home/julius/Ohjelmointi/Raytracer/bin/Debug/voxel renderer
01083000-028e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
322c400000-322c420000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669659                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.16.so
322c620000-322c621000 r--p 00020000 fd:01 669659                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.16.so
322c621000-322c622000 rw-p 00021000 fd:01 669659                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.16.so
322c622000-322c623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
322c800000-322c9ad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669660                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so
322c9ad000-322cbad000 ---p 001ad000 fd:01 669660                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so
322cbad000-322cbb1000 r--p 001ad000 fd:01 669660                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so
322cbb1000-322cbb3000 rw-p 001b1000 fd:01 669660                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so
322cbb3000-322cbb8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
322cc00000-322cc03000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669661                         /usr/lib64/libdl-2.16.so
322cc03000-322ce02000 ---p 00003000 fd:01 669661                         /usr/lib64/libdl-2.16.so
322ce02000-322ce03000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 669661                         /usr/lib64/libdl-2.16.so
322ce03000-322ce04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 669661                         /usr/lib64/libdl-2.16.so
322d000000-322d016000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669662                         /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so
322d016000-322d216000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 669662                         /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so
322d216000-322d217000 r--p 00016000 fd:01 669662                         /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so
322d217000-322d218000 rw-p 00017000 fd:01 669662                         /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so
322d218000-322d21c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
322d400000-322d407000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669663                         /usr/lib64/librt-2.16.so
322d407000-322d606000 ---p 00007000 fd:01 669663                         /usr/lib64/librt-2.16.so
322d606000-322d607000 r--p 00006000 fd:01 669663                         /usr/lib64/librt-2.16.so
322d607000-322d608000 rw-p 00007000 fd:01 669663                         /usr/lib64/librt-2.16.so
322dc00000-322dd00000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 663279                         /usr/lib64/libm-2.16.so
322dd00000-322deff000 ---p 00100000 fd:01 663279                         /usr/lib64/libm-2.16.so
322deff000-322df00000 r--p 000ff000 fd:01 663279                         /usr/lib64/libm-2.16.so
322df00000-322df01000 rw-p 00100000 fd:01 663279                         /usr/lib64/libm-2.16.so
322e800000-322e815000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669679                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20121109.so.1
322e815000-322ea14000 ---p 00015000 fd:01 669679                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20121109.so.1
322ea14000-322ea15000 r--p 00014000 fd:01 669679                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20121109.so.1
322ea15000-322ea16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:01 669679                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20121109.so.1
3230800000-32308e5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669721                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
32308e5000-3230ae4000 ---p 000e5000 fd:01 669721                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
3230ae4000-3230aec000 r--p 000e4000 fd:01 669721                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
3230aec000-3230aee000 rw-p 000ec000 fd:01 669721                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
3230aee000-3230b03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3230c00000-3230d34000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669700                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3230d34000-3230f34000 ---p 00134000 fd:01 669700                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3230f34000-3230f35000 r--p 00134000 fd:01 669700                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3230f35000-3230f3a000 rw-p 00135000 fd:01 669700                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3231000000-3231002000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669698                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3231002000-3231202000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 669698                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3231202000-3231203000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 669698                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3231203000-3231204000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 669698                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3231400000-323141d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669699                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
323141d000-323161c000 ---p 0001d000 fd:01 669699                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
323161c000-323161d000 r--p 0001c000 fd:01 669699                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
323161d000-323161e000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:01 669699                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
3231c00000-3231c11000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669716                         /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3231c11000-3231e10000 ---p 00011000 fd:01 669716                         /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3231e10000-3231e11000 r--p 00010000 fd:01 669716                         /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3231e11000-3231e12000 rw-p 00011000 fd:01 669716                         /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3232c00000-3232c09000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669715                         /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3232c09000-3232e08000 ---p 00009000 fd:01 669715                         /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3232e08000-3232e09000 r--p 00008000 fd:01 669715                         /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3232e09000-3232e0a000 rw-p 00009000 fd:01 669715                         /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3233000000-3233002000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669729                         /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3233002000-3233201000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 669729                         /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3233201000-3233202000 r--p 00001000 fd:01 669729                         /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3233202000-3233203000 rw-p 00002000 fd:01 669729                         /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3233c00000-3233c09000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669731                         /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
3233c09000-3233e08000 ---p 00009000 fd:01 669731                         /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
3233e08000-3233e09000 r--p 00008000 fd:01 669731                         /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
3233e09000-3233e0a000 rw-p 00009000 fd:01 669731                         /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
3235800000-32358bf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 794670                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libGL.so.1.2
32358bf000-32359bf000 ---p 000bf000 fd:01 794670                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libGL.so.1.2
32359bf000-32359e6000 rwxp 000bf000 fd:01 794670                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libGL.so.1.2
32359e6000-3235a08000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3235c00000-3235c0f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 794669                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiuki.so.1.0
3235c0f000-3235d0e000 ---p 0000f000 fd:01 794669                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiuki.so.1.0
3235d0e000-3235d1a000 rw-p 0000e000 fd:01 794669                         /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiuki.so.1.0
323f600000-323f604000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 669766                         /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
323f604000-323f804000 ---p 00004000 fd:01 669766                         /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
323f804000-323f805000 r--p 00004000 fd:01 669766                         /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
323f805000-323f806000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 669766                         /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
3a2e200000-3a2e276000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 655591                         /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.7.0
3a2e276000-3a2e475000 ---p 00076000 fd:01 655591                         /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.7.0
3a2e475000-3a2e47b000 r--p 00075000 fd:01 655591                         /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.7.0
3a2e47b000-3a2e47c000 rw-p 0007b000 fd:01 655591                         /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.7.0
3a2e47c000-3a2e480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c2ce00000-3c2ce7d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 663378                         /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
3c2ce7d000-3c2d07c000 ---p 0007d000 fd:01 663378                         /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
3c2d07c000-3c2d07e000 r--p 0007c000 fd:01 663378                         /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
3c2d07e000-3c2d07f000 rw-p 0007e000 fd:01 663378                         /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
7f2564000000-7f25644c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f25644c2000-7f2568000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f25688c3000-7f25688c4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f25688c4000-7f2568904000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2568904000-7f2568905000 rw-s 1cee5000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f2568905000-7f2568966000 rw-s 1cee4000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f2568966000-7f2568986000 rw-s 00004000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f2568986000-7f2568988000 rw-s 00002000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f2568988000-7f256ab96000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 926157                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libamdocl64.so
7f256ab96000-7f256ad96000 ---p 0220e000 fd:01 926157                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libamdocl64.so
7f256ad96000-7f256afa9000 rw-p 0220e000 fd:01 926157                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libamdocl64.so
7f256afa9000-7f256b0bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256b2bf000-7f256b308000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256b308000-7f256b348000 rw-s 00027000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f256b348000-7f256ba48000 rw-s 00006000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f256ba82000-7f256ba89000 r--s 00000000 fd:01 791548                     /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f256ba89000-7f256bd09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256bd09000-7f256bd5a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 794075                     /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiadlxx.so
7f256bd5a000-7f256be5a000 ---p 00051000 fd:01 794075                     /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiadlxx.so
7f256be5a000-7f256be66000 rw-p 00051000 fd:01 794075                     /usr/lib64/catalyst/libatiadlxx.so
7f256be66000-7f256be76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256be94000-7f256be95000 rw-s 00005000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f256be95000-7f256beb5000 rw-s 00004000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f256beb5000-7f256db10000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 794085                     /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7f256db10000-7f256dc10000 ---p 01c5b000 fd:01 794085                     /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7f256dc10000-7f256dd76000 rwxp 01c5b000 fd:01 794085                     /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7f256dd76000-7f256de9a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256de9a000-7f256de9b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256de9b000-7f256e6a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:27487]
7f256e6a5000-7f256e6ab000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 926159                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libOpenCL.so.1
7f256e6ab000-7f256e8aa000 ---p 00006000 fd:01 926159                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libOpenCL.so.1
7f256e8aa000-7f256e8ab000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 926159                     /opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/libOpenCL.so.1
7f256e8ab000-7f256e8ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256e8b5000-7f256e8b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256e8c8000-7f256e8c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f256e8c9000-7f256e8cb000 rw-s 00002000 00:05 19449                      /dev/ati/card0
7f256e8cb000-7f256e9a7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 656113                     /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.0.0
7f256e9a7000-7f256eba7000 ---p 000dc000 fd:01 656113                     /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.0.0
7f256eba7000-7f256ebaa000 r--p 000dc000 fd:01 656113                     /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.0.0
7f256ebaa000-7f256ebb5000 rw-p 000df000 fd:01 656113                     /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.0.0
7f256ebb5000-7f256ebb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff46c4000-7ffff46e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff47ff000-7ffff4800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Still, I couldn't find the exact reason as to why it should crash. OpenCL, OpenGL and SDL all work as expected before the crash.

So, does anyone know what could possibly cause this kind of crashes with OpenCL?

Comment: Did you consider your code might be causing problems when using incorrect parameters in [clGetPlatformIDs](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html). Does it crash using minimal correct code?

Comment: I doubt it would be caused by incorrect arguments. clGetPlatformIDs returns CL_SUCCESS and as I said before, OpenCL works flawlessly before the crash.

Comment: I would still try it, clGetPlatformIDs can return success and still be writing on wrong memory.

Comment: I get the same crash with clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numDevices).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. numDevices is supposed to be numPlatforms. However, the result stays unchanged.